# Why is $L$ a sum of root spaces $L_\alpha$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a semisimple Lie algebra, and $H$ be a maximal toral subalgebra.
I don't understand why $L$ is a sum of the spaces $L_\alpha$.
[image]

**My confusion**: $H$ is the maximal toral subalgebra. $ad_L H$ consists of endomorphisms of $L$. Each of these endomorphisms commute and therefore can be diagonalized together. **This where I get confused:** Then $End(L)$ has a basis of common eigenvectors of the endomorphisms in $ad_L H$? Then I don't see how we get the $L_\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $H$ is Abelian, $[x,y]=0$ for all $x,y\in H$. Hence, the same holds in $\operatorname{ad}_L(H)$, since this is a Lie algebra homomorphism. Now, this means that we have a family of commuting endomorphisms in $\operatorname{End}(L)$, and as a consequence if they can be diagonalized, they are simultaneously diagonalizable. Since the endomorphisms are *semisimple* this means that their Jordan form is diagonal (e.g. no nilpotent part). Hence, they are simultaneously diagonalizable.

Now, take an eigenbasis $x_1,\ldots, x_k$ of $L$, and then define $\alpha_i(h)$ to be the unique scalar such that $[h,x_i]=\alpha_i(h)x_i$. Then, defining $L_\alpha$ as above, it becomes clear that $L=\bigoplus_{i=1}^k L_{\alpha_i}$. Essentially, these functions $\alpha_i$ keep track of the eigenvalue that $h$ takes on $x_i$ as a function of $h$.

Comment: can you explain why in general we take $L=\oplus L_{\alpha}$ where $\alpha$ is in the whole $h^*$ not only finite set as you write?